# How to get access to show values via anuglar from spring rest?

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-restcontroller

I have two entities, `Disc` and `DiscLog`:

Disc Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "disc")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Disc implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    private Connection connection;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "disc", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonIgnore
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<DiscLog> discLogs = new HashSet<>();

 ...
}
```

DiscLog entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "disc_log")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class DiscLog implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "util", nullable = false)
    private Double util;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "svctim", nullable = false)
    private Double svctim;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "await", nullable = false)
    private Double await;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "avgqusz", nullable = false)
    private Double avgqusz;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "avgrqsz", nullable = false)
    private Double avgrqsz;

    @Column(name = "date", insertable = false, columnDefinition = "now()")
    private ZonedDateTime date;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    private Disc disc;

    ...
```

I am using angularJS so part of my HTML looks like:

```
         <dd>
            <span>{{vm.disc.name}}</span>
        </dd>
```

How to display for example disc -> discLog -> util value? 
I tried

```
     <dd>
        <span>{{vm.disc.disclog.util}}</span>
    </dd>
```

and this display nothing.

My rest looks like:

```
   @GetMapping("/discs/{id}")
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<Disc> getDisc(@PathVariable Long id) {
        log.debug("REST request to get Disc : {}", id);
        Disc disc = discRepository.findOne(id);
        return ResponseUtil.wrapOrNotFound(Optional.ofNullable(disc));
    }
```

Anuglar service:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('deviceManagerApp')
        .factory('Disc', Disc);

    Disc.$inject = ['$resource'];

    function Disc ($resource) {
        var resourceUrl =  'api/discs/:id';

        return $resource(resourceUrl, {}, {
            'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: true},
            'get': {
                method: 'GET',
                transformResponse: function (data) {
                    if (data) {
                        data = angular.fromJson(data);
                    }
                    return data;
                }
            },
            'update': { method:'PUT' }
        });
    }
})();
```

Comment: What does the angular service part actually look like?

Comment: @Katana24 I add angular service.

Comment: AFAIK, `@JsonIgnore` won't let `discLogs` collection to be serialized and sent to your frontend + I noticed that in your angular code you're using `discLog` instead of `discLogs`

Answer (score 0):

Disc file has a set of Set objects. Hence you have to iterate through each DiscLog object in every Disc object in the front end.

So you cannot access discLog directly with {{vm.disc.disclog.util}}. Instead use:

{{vm.disc.disclog[i].util}} where i=0,1,2,3...

Example:

```
<sometag ng-repeat="i in objectsLength"> {{vm.disc.disclog[i].util}}</sometag>
```

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: Still, I can't display data.

Comment: Can you please show us console.log(data) in your http call?

Answer (score 0):

Well, your `disc` contains a Set of `discLogs`.
So you have to call:

```
<dd>
    <span>{{vm.disc.discLogs[0].util}}</span>
</dd>
```